# 86 links indexed by Google Search Console. Shown in search results, but later removed from search results (still shown in the Search Console)

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-index

I have 86 links for my site `example.com` successfully indexed by Google Search Console. They first appeared in Google's search results. But after a few days, most of the links disappeared. Currently, only 13 links are shown in search results when pointing to site:example.com

I know searching using "site:xxx.com" is not reliable. I tried to manually search (using keywords and phrases) for those links reported indexed but not shown in search results, and yes, they could not be found. I can confirm this because the search results showed the links in my old website.

Am I being penalized by Google for doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: There are 5 reasons for it. Have you looked at them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the content on your old website the same as the content on this site?  Why is the old site still around?  Are you planning and putting in a redirect?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The old website is under Wordpress. I have yet to delete it. Will do soon. I have just re-built my new website at a shared hosting account. And the content is totally new (compared to the ones in Wordpress).

Comment: @RohitGupta Yes, I have looked into it many times. I can't correlate anything. But more than 96 links are under "Discovered - currently not indexed".

Comment: I have yet to see a case where something isn't indexed when Google says it is.  Try searching for a unique 6 to 10 word phrase from the page in quotes.  If that turns up your old site, your content would be way to similar.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, I have done that. I have 85 links indexed by Google Search Console. But actually, only 13 links can be found. I have tried to search for some phrases from pages indexed by Google, and they are not shown in search results.

Comment: Can you share some example URLs?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller

https://lawrence.com.my/tours/penang/270-kch-half-day-kuala-lumpur-putrajaya-culture-history-city-tour-by-car
https://lawrence.com.my/tours/penang/268-kcf-full-day-kuala-lumpur-putrajaya-culture-history-city-tour-by-car
https://lawrence.com.my/tours/penang/218-icf-full-day-penang-ipoh-tour-by-car
https://lawrence.com.my/reviews/136-amal-pollack-united-states
https://lawrence.com.my/reviews/158-vivienne-mccullagh-australia 

All the above are reported indexed by GSC but not found when I do site:lawrence.com.my or search for the keywords/phrases.

Comment: The first one is indexed: https://www.google.com/search?tbs=li:1&num=30&q=%22Half-Day+Kuala+Lumpur%2C+Putrajaya+Culture+%26+History+City+Tour+%22

Comment: Search for the URL itself and you'll see that Google has in in in the index.

Comment: Then you can search for text from the snippet that Google shows, and it comes up for that too.

Comment: It looks like maybe Google isn't able to crawl all the content on the page or something.

Answer (score 1):

I just picked a page at random `https://lawrence.com.my/tour/penang` and checked it for errors.  To get the full benefit from GSE, you really need to clean up the html and css.  Otherwise there is a danger thae the GSE can not evaluate your page.

One example of error is

```html
<meta property="og:title" content=Private Local Tour Guide in Penang & KL>
```

You need quotes for the value of `content`, like so

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="Private Local Tour Guide in Penang & KL">
```

There are many sites that will check your pages.  I am using an addon for Chrome to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I will check.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out that you have been penalized, you need to check those addresses with keywords. I understood from the questions that you did not do this.
Please check again after a few weeks, maybe there is a problem with reporting.
If the problem is not with reporting, maybe your pages had a low rank in the target words.

Comment: The OP has already tried keywords!

Comment: Yes. I have tried keywords.